# Is netty's udp running in single-threaded mode?

Tags: udp, netty, single-threaded

Is netty's udp running in single-threaded mode?

I have configured the NioDatagramChannelFactory like below:

new NioDatagramChannelFactory(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4), 4));

But, when I running the code as a server, and lunch more than 20 clients to send udp packages continuously to it, the server still use only one worker thread.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally it should use 4 worker threads here. So how are you seeing that it only use one thread ? Did you check with jstack to see how many worker threads are running ?

You should also use

`new NioDatagramChannelFactory(Executors.newCachedThreadPool(), 4));`

This should take care of having at max. 4 worker threads.

Comment: Norman, I tested it by changing the EchoServer by changing the channel factory to  NioDatagramChannelFactory, but I can only see one worker thread, but with the NioServerChannelFactory, I can see 8 worker threads. (tested both with more than 20 clients), I tested with my fork at branch 3 (last commit is 2c2d64a75ea9c636c90b8b16293296a47c7cfd32), I could not test with latest 3 branch.